# Yocto - Add Custom Driver

Tags: linux, module, kernel, yocto

I need realtek-8192cu driver in my linux version.

The default driver shipped with kernel is not suitable for me.

I want to use a custom version of driver like  https://github.com/desflynn/realtek-8192cu-concurrent-softAP.

How to create a recipe for that job.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

one possibility is to use the bitbake recipe *hello-mod_0.1.bb* as starting point to build a recipe for external kernel modules. It can be found at *openembedded-core/meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod/hello-mod_0.1.bb*

The Reference to Incorporating Out-of-Tree Modules: *https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules*